# Limit of Expected values

Tags: probability-theory

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space.

Let $\{X_n : n \geq 1 \}$ be a sequence of Independent random variables. $$E(X_n) = 0 \; , \; Var(X_n) = 1 \; \; \forall n $$

Show that for any $Y \in L^2$ it is neccesarily true that $$E(X_nY) \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 $$

Stuck on this problem. I tryed to use dominated convergence but I could neither prove the pointwise limit nor find a dominating function. Is this the wrong approach?

Comment: As a first approach, could you prove that $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nE(X_kY)\to0\ ?$$

Comment: Try Dids approach since it makes no assumptions

Comment: @Did I was able to show your expression using linearity of the expectation and Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: Unsure how it helps though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially a problem about Hilbert space theory. First note that independence yields
$$
\Bbb{E}(X_n X_m) = \Bbb {E}(X_n) \Bbb {E}(X_m)=0
$$
for $n \neq  m $. In combination with your variance assumption, we see that $(X_n)_n $ is an orthonormal system in $L^2$.

Now, **Bessel's inequality** states that
$$
\sum_n |\Bbb {E}(X_n Y)|^2 \leq \Vert Y\Vert_{L^2}^2
$$
for $Y \in L^2$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, thank you very much ! .  I gues it helps to view things differently. My mind was too stuck up on probability concepts.